# how to retrieve in a sql many to many relationships inner join query all the instances a user is involved with

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django, postgresql

How can I retrieve all the instances a user is part of in a `Many to Many relationship` in `SQL`. (PostgreSQL)

I have the following table using `django`:

## models.py

```
...

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
...

User = get_user_model()


class Membership(models.Model):

    ...
    member = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="user_membership")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## query

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)

user.user_membership.all()

# result => give me all instances where user 1 is associated in Member table
```

What would be the equivalent in `SQL` (might be called - many to many inner join) of the above `django` query?

Any help would be much appreciated

I have tried

```
SELECT *
FROM membership
INNER JOIN users 
ON membership.member = users.id
```

but it does not seem to work

Comment: `user.membership_set.all()`

Comment: @raphael im looking for the `sql` equivalent, not django orm query as the one mentioned above work

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-Many relations always use a third table to record the relationship, this happens behind the ORM.

What you want is something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_membership um 
INNER JOIN membership m ON um.id_membership = m.id 
INNER JOIN users u ON um.id_user = u.id
WHERE u.id = 1
```

If you didn't undersand something, ask me again, english isn't my first language.